# How can I store columns from excel to python3.6?

Tags: python, excel

I'm slowly working my way in using spyder Python3.6, hope you can give me some solutions to this question:

An Excel file [ c1.xlsx ] which contains 10 columns (from column a to e) and 20 rows(from row 2 to 21), now I want to create a sheet using python (columns namely A, B, C, E). I need all data from these 20 rows from column a, b, c and e.

So I hope I will get this as [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLbgS.jpg)

I alread have some codes:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import os

    dir = os.path.join('..' , 'Climate')
    fname = 'C1.xlsx'
    fpath = os.path.join(dir,fname)
    data = pd.read_excel(fpath,sheetname = 'sheet1',header=0)

    df_Ct = pd.columns = (['A', 'B', 'C', 'E'])
```

how can I continue to read these values?

Comment: how does your data variable look like? Use data.head().to_dict() to share here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation, "read_excel" returns a DataFrame. So you already have the data.

Then, you can access a column in the DataFrame by referring to its name, like:

df['A']

You can then construct a new data frame and write it out.

Comment: Thank you! Although I solved the question by something like "data.iloc[:,0:5]"